# How is "How to save an rTorrent session?" not a valid title?

Tags: support

I can't create the question "How to save an rTorrent session?" on superuser. It complains that it is not a real question. How can I fix it?

Comment: If that's exactly what you entered, nothing there should be blocked. Perhaps you tried to use a blacklisted tag?

Comment: You asked it, then you deleted it? huh? http://superuser.com/q/809038/4377

Comment: I had one tag: rtorrent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ftfy. Question looks fine to me - though I had to undelete it to check. If you can't undelete it yourself, feel free to flag and I'll fix it.

Comment: I can't undelete when a mod has deleted it. It's OK. I deleted it because the answer is in black in white in the manual.

Comment: @Synesso - You can see your own deleted questions which means you can flag a question to be undeleted.

Comment: @ramhound after which it says it was deleted by a moderator, so my vote to undelete won't do anything